# Why does Android Studio Dart Analysis throws error for required keyword?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a **Coordinate** Class where both parameters are required.

**Both Android Studio and Visual Studio Code do not recognize the *required* keyword.**

[image: required]

### Why does Dart Analysis give **Undefined class required** error?

```
 required isn't a type.
Try correcting the name to match an existing type.
```

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Coordinate coordinate = Coordinate(lon: 3.4, lat: 2.3);

    return Container(
      child: Text(coordinate.lat.toString()),
    );
  }
}

class Coordinate {
  double lon;
  double lat;
  Coordinate({required lon, required lat});
}
```

**Dart SDK version**: 2.12.3 (stable)

Comment: What Dart version requirement is specified in your `pubspec.yaml` file? The minimum version should be set to 2.12.0 since the `required` keyword is first introduced here.

Comment: Remove all dart and flutter sdks fom your system and do a clean install tk e sure you're running the latest stable version of dart. Like you mentioned in the chat have 2 versions running simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

Is the version of `Dart` updated to 2.12 on your environment?

The second error says `required` is not a valid keyword, the `required` keyword was added in Dart 2.12.

**Note**: The compiler is parsing the `required` keyword as a type and as it does not find the type `required` defined anywhere in the project it interprets it is as `dynamic`, Hence the error.

This is the answer to the question

*Why does Android Studio Dart Analysis throws error for required keyword?*

*Now, If it is still not working for you, I suggest you open a new issue with the appropriate tags about the sdk install/environment issues you have. As this question has served its purpose*

Comment: Flutter 2.2.0-10.1.pre • channel beta •

Tools • Dart 2.13.0 (build 2.13.0-211.6.beta)

Comment: Can you confirm is this is the version android-studio is using? I copied the code sample above and I do not get any errors.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to get the dart version from android studio.

Comment: It should be in the Languages and Framework settings, A quick way to find it would be to open settings and search for Dart

Comment: I don't get it.  I have changed into the stable channel. Android Studio is definitely using dart SDK 2.12.3

Comment: Well essentially the problem is that the compiler is not recognizing the required keyword. We need to get that issue out of the way. Seems highly likely that this is an environment error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231544/discussion-between-cem-kaan-and-rohan-thacker).

Comment: Do consider marking this as the accepted answer, so we can help others with the same issue in the future

Comment: The question asked has been answered and explained. There is a clear explanation as to why the code wont compile. Your system has dart set up incorrectly and thats out of the scope of this question..